# Xencenter guest will not boot

Tags: xenserver

I have xen server free edition.
Today one of the guest VM was very loaded and I decided to reboot it.
Now it can not start. It is with Ubuntu 10.04 Server.
The machine is shown as running in xsconsole and in windows Xen control center. It shows 100 % CPU and 100 % RAM usage. The console shows nothing (it doesn't show boot process). And the worst is that I have no backup.
Is there any advice how to see what is going on.
I exported it to file and now I am trying it to import it into another server, because I can't reboot the physical server it runs on. Can this save me (the reboot of the server)

Thank you

Comment: First thing I'd do is run 'xe task-list' from command line on the Xen server to get the status of all tasks. Your reboot task might be pending and be waiting for another task to complete before it is executed. You can then try and cancel the blocking task.

Comment: Just in case someone's having this same problem, I made it work again here: http://serverfault.com/questions/656114/xenserver-6-2-vm-100-cpu-and-100-memory-usage-and-wont-boot/656115#656115

Answer (score 1):

I would try xe-toolstack-restart. this will restart all associated services without needing to reboot the cms.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this procedure:

1. Get the uuid of the hung VM: `xe vm-list name-label=VMname`
2. Find the VM domain id: `list_domains | grep [uuid]`
3. Destroy the VM domain: `/opt/xensource/debug/destroy_domain -domid [domain id]`
4. Reboot the VM: `xe vm-reboot name-label=VMname --force`

This solved my problems with hanging VM's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xe task-cancel command to kill the process. If all else fails try restarting the XenServer API service: service xapi restart