# XenServer 6.2 VM 100% CPU and 100% memory usage and won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, xenserver, memory-usage, cpu-usage, grub2

I had this problem today after a power failure.

I had 2 vms and one of them won't boot and was using 100% of CPU and 100% of memory.

Since it was very dificult to solve (at least for me) I want to detail here the steps I've made to fix it, mixing many tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. [This helped me](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/359307-ubuntu-x64-wont-boot-after-power-failure/#entry1851517):

> It could be possible that the problem was GRUB not sending signal video.
>
> I've seen many threads regarding this, and it is highly probable that my VM's were stuck **at this GRUB screen where you MUST select the OS to boot** (giving the fact that they **booted by pressing enter**).
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/372164/how-to-load-ubuntu-server-automatically-in-grub
>
> Because this happened to me after power failures also, in a non-virtualized pc.

Just clicked in the blank area, hit enter, and it started booting.

Comment: Yes, that question belongs to me lol :P

Answer (score 3):

First, I tried to use the Ubuntu server installation CD and go to Recue a Broken System, then tried to reinstall GRUB, but it failed.

Then I shut down the failing VM with Force Shutdown.

Secondly, listed the VMs in the XenCenter Console

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vm-list
uuid ( RO)           : d56d5ae8-62de-5e7e-41f9-1bd707d727d9
     name-label ( RW): fdev-appgw
    power-state ( RO): halted


uuid ( RO)           : 87aba275-0e05-4160-bebf-efc85fe93386
     name-label ( RW): fdev-tracker
    power-state ( RO): halted


uuid ( RO)           : c81439c2-a345-4f04-947e-34554718ce7e
     name-label ( RW): Control domain on host: fdev-xen01
    power-state ( RO): running
```

fdev-tracker was the one failing.

Listed it's disks. I must admit I don't know why I have 2 disks here, since I am relatively newbie to Linux. But I used the first one, the one that says Device: hdb

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-list vm-name-label=fdev-tracker
uuid ( RO)             : d461e06d-9cc3-7762-f141-0b3d2abe7b3c
          vm-uuid ( RO): 87aba275-0e05-4160-bebf-efc85fe93386
    vm-name-label ( RO): fdev-tracker
         vdi-uuid ( RO): 92dd9489-b450-4766-8853-b8b2fc9597ad
            empty ( RO): false
           device ( RO): hdb


uuid ( RO)             : 969fc0c8-1fcf-ed2c-ed6e-a71dc3c359d9
          vm-uuid ( RO): 87aba275-0e05-4160-bebf-efc85fe93386
    vm-name-label ( RO): fdev-tracker
         vdi-uuid ( RO): ba9e2ed8-c9db-4f95-8f14-2d51c99ea992
            empty ( RO): false
           device ( RO): hdd
```

After it I put this commands to be able to mount the disk in my other Linux VM. I don't know exactly what they do, but it is what the tutorials says.
Please note that d56d5ae8-62de-5e7e-41f9-1bd707d727d9 is the UUID of the *working* VM. I had problems before because the tutorial didn't do clear on this.
92dd9489-b450-4766-8853-b8b2fc9597ad is the UUID of the *failing* machine VDI.

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-create vm-uuid=d56d5ae8-62de-5e7e-41f9-1bd707d727d9 vdi-uuid=92dd9489-b450-4766-8853-b8b2fc9597ad device=autodetect
91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7
```

It outputs an UUID. I used it to plug it to the working machine.

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-plug uuid=91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7
```

After it I ssh'ed the working VM and entered `parted`:

```
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/xvda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print devices                                                    
/dev/xvda (10,7GB)
/dev/xvdb (21,5GB)
(parted) quit
```

`/dev/xvdb` this one, of 21 GB is the disk of the failing VM.

I've tried to do a fsck on it:

```
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/xvdb
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/xvdb
/dev/xvdb: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

But I remembered that when I formatted, it had 2 partitions, one for the entire filesystem (ext4) and other for swap (ext3 I think). So maybe that was causing trouble.

Then I saw another tutorial, it was using a program called `kpartx`. I didn't have it, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install kpartx
```

I then did:

```
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo kpartx -a /dev/xvdb
```

It seems that it makes the partitions visible or something like that. They are now in /dev/mapper/

```
    jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/mapper/   #tab press
    control  xvdb1    xvdb2    xvdb5

So I made the fsck on all xvdb*:

jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/mapper/xvdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/mapper/xvdb1: Updating bad block inode.

      126881 inodes used (10.05%, out of 1262320)
          65 non-contiguous files (0.1%)
         120 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 117890/29
      778957 blocks used (15.43%, out of 5047040)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

       99695 regular files
       17528 directories
          55 character device files
          25 block device files
           0 fifos
          28 links
        9564 symbolic links (8869 fast symbolic links)
           5 sockets
------------
      126900 files
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/mapper/xvdb
xvdb1  xvdb2  xvdb5  
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/mapper/xvdb2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/mapper/xvdb2
Could this be a zero-length partition?
jsivil@appgw:/proc$ sudo fsck -p -c -v -f /dev/mapper/xvdb5
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.swap: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.swap for /dev/mapper/xvdb5
```

I  don't know why it failed on xvdb2 (nor what it is, because for me it should have only 2 partitions). xvdb5 was swap, so that wasn't important.
Next, I've tried to mount to see if I was able to see my files (I was able using the Ubuntu Server CD), but I was curious.

```
cd to /run/shm
jsivil@appgw:/run/shm$ mkdir /run/shm/a
jsivil@appgw:/run/shm$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/xvdb1 a
```

I cd'ed to "a" and all was there. I umount ed it.

Next, I returned to the primary guide about XenServer and tried to unplug it from VM

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-unplug uuid=91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7
The VM rejected the attempt to detach the device.
type: VBD
ref: 91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7
msg:
```

It seems that some of the previous steps in the working VM had the disk in a "in use" state or something.

So I rebooted the working VM. Tried to do it again, but the VM was still rebooting. So I got another error. Waited until it finished and was able to do it.

```
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-unplug uuid=91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7 
You attempted an operation on a VM which requires PV drivers to be installed but the drivers were not detected.
vm: d56d5ae8-62de-5e7e-41f9-1bd707d727d9 (fdev-appgw)
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-unplug uuid=91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7 
[root@xen01 ~]# xe vbd-destroy  uuid=91022555-2b86-4faf-cce1-eb62efc8aab7
```

After all this, I've tried to boot the *failing* machine, but I had no luck :(
The same problem was there, 100% CPU and 100% memory.

I put on the Ubuntu Server Installation CD (I have it in ISO Storage) and forced reboot. Entered Rescue Broken System, and mounted xvdb1 as my root filesystem. After it, I went to "Reinstall GRUB". Remember it was failing previously, but this time it succeded.

I ejected the CD and rebooted.

My VM is working again!!!

This seems to be a rare problem because I couldn't find much information about this, only one guy on ServerFault, but with no working answer (like destroying vm domain or something like that).

I hope it helps somebody and feel free to edit this and clear the concepts that I don't know about.